# how to make a custom row in BaseAdapter android

Tags: android, baseadapter

```
private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{       
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mOnlineIcon;
    private Bitmap mOfflineIcon;        

    private FriendInfo[] friends = null;


    public FriendListAdapter(Context context) {
        super();            

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        mOnlineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.greenstar);
        mOfflineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.redstar);

    }

    public void setFriendList(FriendInfo[] friends)
    {
        this.friends = friends;
    }


    public int getCount() {     

        return friends.length;
    }


    public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {           

        return friends[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;


            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
            // by ListView is null.
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_screen, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);   

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }   
            else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
            holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friends[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

how to make some like bubble speech in my output textview??

Comment: I think you should try setting a bubble like image as a background to your raw layout.

Comment: Or use a drawable with rounded corners, would be nicer.

Comment: how to implements that drawable @DoctorDbx coz im newbie in android develope

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    Context _scontext;
    LayoutInflater _inflater;
    ArrayList<ProductsDataModel> data;

    public ProductsAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ProductsDataModel> arraylist) {
        this._scontext = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView ends_in,discount_rate;
        ImageView set_product_image;
        Button go_for_sale;
        _inflater = (LayoutInflater) _scontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_display_custom_layout_phone, parent, false);


        ends_in  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_time_left);
        discount_rate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_discount);        
        set_product_image  =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        go_for_sale = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.go_for_sale);
        go_for_sale.setTag(position);
        set_product_image.setTag(position);
        Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/georgia.ttf");
        ends_in.setTypeface(mFont);
        discount_rate.setTypeface(mFont);

        ProductsDataModel obj=data.get(position);

        long timeInMilliseconds = Long.valueOf(obj.getEnds_at());
        long end = timeInMilliseconds * 1000;
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = end - current;
        int dayCount = (int) diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        int hours_left = (int) ((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        int minutes_left = (int) ((diff / (1000 * 60 )) % 60);
        int seconds_left = (int) ((diff/1000)%60);
        System.out.println("A"+hours_left);
        System.out.println("B"+minutes_left);
        System.out.println("C"+seconds_left);

        String s = Integer.toString(dayCount) + " Days" +" "+ Integer.toString(hours_left) + ":" + Integer.toString(minutes_left) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds_left);
        ends_in.setText(s);
        discount_rate.setText(obj.getDiscount_text());

        String a="https:"+obj.getTeaser_url();      
        System.out.println("value of a is+"+a);

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(_scontext);
        aq.id(set_product_image).image(a);




        return itemView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a drawable and set it to the background of your background view.

in res/drawable (you may need to create the drawable folder) create bubbleback.xml and 
add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

<stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"
        />

<padding android:left="3dp"
         android:top="3dp"
         android:right="3dp"
         android:bottom="3dp"
         /> 

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
         android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Save and Set the background of the top most view of friend_list_screen to the bubbleback drawable.